# Add new JS class and template to aurelia project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia, but am working on an existing project and learning as I go.
I want to add a javascript class file and have NPM include it in the build, but I cannot find clear documentation on how to do that.

It is not a complex class and does not require an html template.

Comment: just an FYI, NPM is not responsible for the build - you can run `au build` yourself. `npm scripts` are just for convenience. also, you can see the build process itslef under `aurelia_project\tasks\build`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the .js file containing your class to your src folder and add the following to import it in the file you intend to use the class.

```
import * as MyClass from './my-classs';
```

Answer (score 1):

following the convention, you can create a class with the below...

```
export class MyClass {
    myProperty = 'foo';
    myOtherProperty = { key:'value' };

    constructor() {
        // constructor stuff (optional of course)
    }

    myMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewModel, for example...

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { MyClass } from 'path/to/my-class';

@inject(MyClass)
export class MyViewModel {
    constructor(myClass){
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    attached() {
        console.log(this.myClass.myProperty);
        this.myClass.myMethod();
    }
}
```

The way you import your class does depend on whether it's written as a module or not.  If it's not a module, you'll have to write it out as @john-little mentioned.

The `MyClass` will automatically be a singleton until you make it transient (see https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/dependency-injection#object-lifetime-child-containers-and-default-behavior)